# unity c# Create multiple countdown timer each with own current time

Tags: c#

I have a countdown timer script that takes an input of a float and counts down that many seconds. It then changes a boolean to true when the countdown has finished. When I start the timer again it changes the boolean back to false. I currently have 3 instances of this timer but plan to have more. However when I start one of the timers. It resets the current time of all the other timers.

How can I make it so that all the timers do not interfere with each other?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SimpleTimer: MonoBehaviour {

    float _targetTime;
    bool _ended;

    void Start()
    {
        _targetTime = 1.0f;
        _ended = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        _targetTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (_targetTime <= 0.0f)
        {
            timerEnded();
        }

    }

    void timerEnded()
    {
        _ended = true;
    }

    public void restart (float time)
    {
        _targetTime = time;
        _ended = false;
    }

    public bool ended
    {
        get { return _ended; }
        set { _ended = value; }
    }

}
```